# C++ Creating function closure

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to create function closure using nested functions. Is something like this possible in C++?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include <functional>

double f1(double &x)
{
  double f2 (double &y)
    {
      return (x*y);
     }
  // auto fptr = std::function<double(double)> = &f2();
  //return fptr; 
}


int main()
{
double x={10.0}, y={11.0};
std::function<double(double)> foo=&f1;
//auto res1 = f1(fptr(x));  

    return 0;
}
```

Here is example with lambda. I want to use function and function returning pointer (std::function) instead of lambda.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <functional>

std::function<double(double)> f3(double x)    {
  return ( [x](double y) {return x*y;});
}

int main()   {
double res1 = f3(10.0)(11.0);   
std::cout<<res1;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++17 does not support nested-functions using free-function syntax, but you can use lambdas or nested-classes with member functions.

Comment: Why won't you use lambdas? It seems to me like that's exactly what you need?

Comment: You can not capture state with a function. For this you need an object. Thus you cn do it with a functor, and since lambda are just a generalization of a functor you can also do it with lambdas.

Comment: The only ways you can create nested functions in C++ are as static members of function-scope classes, or as lambdas (someone will come along shortly and tell you lambdas are implemented using statics). In both cases you are limited by the scoping rules such that the function-local definition is not available in the namespace. You can'of course return a pointer to the nested function, but that is not the same as accessing it by its name directly.

Comment: XY problem? Lambda's were designed specifically to address this problem. Why don't you like them?

Comment: A function can also return a lambda using `auto` return types.

Comment: The next-nearest thing is to use namespaces or classes to represent your nesting, and the perhaps operator() or a "well-known" function name to name your actual function.

Comment: C++ has a way to create closures with lambdas. No other way.

Comment: I don't follow, in your lambda example. The lambda inside the f3 returns a double (determined by the type returned by the return statement, in this case double) & f3 returns a function that takes a double. what you want your return type of f3 be here? or did I miss something?